# What is better to use in this sentence? for or on

Tags: prepositions

What preposition is better to use in this case?

> I am the industrial system designer **for** the new logistic projects.

> I am the industrial system designer **on** new logistic projects.

If you would structure the sentence differently, please feel free to say it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean to use "the" in one sentence but not the other? It's easier to directly compare changes in a sentence if they're the *only* change

Answer (score 2):

Since the purpose of the sentence is to inform someone of your **role** using "for" makes more since because you were hired **for** the purpose of designing systems **for** the new projects. Yes, you will work "on" on the projects, but the sentence is based on your purpose or role and thus "for" fits better.